# SlowCheetah for app.config transform - Transform not an option after installation

Tags: msbuild, slowcheetah

I may be doing something wrong, but I do not see any options to transform app.config or other XML documents after installing the latest Nuget package in solutions. I've tried two solutions, one an MVC App and another a Console App. Neither offered any additional transformations. I opened the project file for the MVC App and see the SlowCheetah definitions and import statements. Found the bug to expand the SC_ to SlowCheetah_ in the  Property Group with Label="SLowCheetah".

I am using Visual Studio 2010 sp1 for this set of projects.

Comment: Well I feel pretty stupid, but I did figure it out. I confused the Nuget package with the VSIX deployment of SlowCheetah with all of the work Sayed has been doing to make it easier to install and use. Installing the Visual Studio Extension (VSIX), instead of just the Nuget package for the project, enabled the transform menu when right-clicking on app.config. Problem solved.

Comment: Yep that is correct. The VS extension adds the Add Transform menu option.